# How to remove CGContext for line in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitouch, uibezierpath

I am moving and adding lines with these two lines.

```
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 185);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 185);
```

I want to know that how can I remove line (like CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 185); //addline). I want to remove line when I move or clear line color if my array == 2;

then my line color will be clear color or line remove the position when I moved forward.

Any Idea or suggestion would be highly welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove line"? What does `array == 2` have to do with it? Is it just a copy & paste bug that all points are the same?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClearRect

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in a `drawRect:` method, you can simply just draw the line if it needs to be and not do anything if you want to clear it. The `drawRect:` method gets called many times and the view is essentially "cleared" before you start drawing. So your code might look something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // other drawing code and declaration of array variable...
    if ([array count] == 2) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 185);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 185);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i have faced. Directly i can not do it so i have used some tricky logic as below and worked for me. I just give hint, Hope this logic will help you.

I have button with underline drawn using drawRect method, so in some match cases i need to remove it, so i do like this:

**Note: "isRemoveUnderLine" is Bool property in my custom button class**

```
if ([array count] == 2) {
     myButton.isRemoveUnderLine = YES;
     [myButton setNeedsDisplay];  //it will update your button context and call drawRect method again...
}
```

//Code for drawRect method as below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if(_isRemoveUnderLine)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    else
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.currentTitleColor.CGColor);

...
...
}
```

Hope you get some hint to fix with your logic!!!